# jQuery: Using .find and .addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using Ajax to input some data from a JSON file. Everything is inserting fine except that I want to add the class `'checked'` to an certain amount `<span>`'s depending on the rating set within the JSON file. (For example a film with a rating of 3 will add the class `'checked'` to the first 3 `span`'s).

Here is my JS so far just trying to get it to work with a rating of 3:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.getJSON("data/films.json",function(films){
       $.each(films, function(index,film){
            var $newLi = $('<div class="film"><img class="pure-u-2-5" src='+film.img+'/><div class="pure-u-2-5"><ul><li><b>Title:</b> '+film.title+'</li><li><b>Genre:</b> '+film.genre+'</li><li><b>Director:</b> '+film.director+'</li><li><b>Release Date:</b> '+film.release+'</li><div class="star"><span class="star1 fa fa-star"></span> <span class="star2 fa fa-star"></span> <span class="star3 fa fa-star"></span> <span class="star4 fa fa-star"></span> <span class="star5 fa fa-star"></span></div></div>');

            if (film.rating===3){
                $(".star").find("star1").addClass("checked");
                $(".star").find("star2").addClass("checked");
                $(".star").find("star3").addClass("checked");
            }

            $(".showFilm").append($newLi);

            })

       });

       }) ;
```

### The Problem

The checked class should change the colour of the span, however it is not doing so.

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: @Sidney, The checked class should change the colour of the span, however it is not doing so.

Comment: Your find selector is looking for elements with tagNames of star1, etc.  Should that be class names?

Comment: There are a bunch of issues with the code.

Comment: To answer this question properly is necessary to see a sample of the JSON you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple issues:

1. The problem is you are selecting all the stars on the page
2. The stars you are actually trying to select have yet to add to the DOM
3. Your class selectors are missing the `.`

So you can select the elements in the jQuery object and fix your selector

```
var $newLi = $('<div class="film"><img class="pure-u-2-5" src='+film.img+'/><div class="pure-u-2-5"><ul><li><b>Title:</b> '+film.title+'</li><li><b>Genre:</b> '+film.genre+'</li><li><b>Director:</b> '+film.director+'</li><li><b>Release Date:</b> '+film.release+'</li><div class="star"><span class="star1 fa fa-star"></span> <span class="star2 fa fa-star"></span> <span class="star3 fa fa-star"></span> <span class="star4 fa fa-star"></span> <span class="star5 fa fa-star"></span></div></div>');

if (film.rating===3){
  $newLi.find(".star .star1").addClass("checked");
  $newLi.find(".star .star2").addClass("checked");
  $newLi.find(".star .star3").addClass("checked");
}

$(".showFilm").append($newLi);
```

How can it be improved? Instead of selecting each one and also having multtiple ifs, add the class to the group based on count.

```
$newLi.find(".star .fa-star").slice(0, film.rating-1).addClass("checked");
```

Comment: Thanks this is working, also thank you for the improvement, that was my next concern. What is the purpose of the '-1' after film.rating? As with this it was giving each instance a rating of 1 less than it should have been.

Answer (score 1):

`film.rating` is probably a string, which you're trying to compare to a number like so:

```
if (film.rating===3)
```

There are a couple solutions:

1. Use double-equals, which will treat `film.rating` as a number for the comparison:

   if (film.rating == 3)
2. Explicitly convert `film.rating` to a number by prepending a plus sign:

   if (+film.rating == 3)

Also note that you need a period before any classnames (such as star1).  Change:

```
$(".star").find("star1").addClass("checked");
$(".star").find("star2").addClass("checked");
$(".star").find("star3").addClass("checked");
```

… to:

```
$(".star").find(".star1").addClass("checked");
$(".star").find(".star2").addClass("checked");
$(".star").find(".star3").addClass("checked");
```

Comment: I would do a cycle to check the stars depending of the number of stars dynamically

Answer (score 0):

It's untested but should work

```
function makeFilmHTML (film) {
    var rating = film.rating;
    var html = [
    '<div class="film">',
      '<img class="pure-u-2-5" src="',film.img,'"/>',
      '<div class="pure-u-2-5">',
        '<ul>',
          '<li><b>Title:</b> ',film.title,'</li>',
          '<li><b>Genre:</b> ',film.genre,'</li>',
          '<li><b>Director:</b> ',film.director,'</li>',
          '<li><b>Release Date:</b> ',film.release,'</li>',
        '</ul>',
      '</div>',
      '<div class="star">',
        '<span class="star1 fa fa-star"></span>',
        '<span class="star2 fa fa-star"></span>',
        '<span class="star3 fa fa-star"></span>',
        '<span class="star4 fa fa-star"></span>',
        '<span class="star5 fa fa-star"></span>',
      '</div>',
    '</div>'
  ].join('');

  html = $(html);
  html.find('.star > .fa-star:lt('+ rating +')').addClass('checked');

  return html;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   $.getJSON("data/films.json",function(films){
       $.each(films, function(index,film){
            var $filmHTML = makeFilmHTML(film);

            $(".showFilm").append($filmHTML);
       });
   });
}) ;
```